# Review Queues Bug?

Tags: bug, review

Quite often, I'm guessing since the [Close Vote Review Queue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/how-to-shrink-the-close-vote-review-queue) is pretty much always greater than 200, there is a red dot on my Review Queue button indicating that some review queue is abnormally large. This wouldn't be a problem, except that I still get the red dot even when I've performed my maximum 20 reviews in that same queue. Even that wouldn't be a problem, except that sometimes the red dot is there, and sometimes the red dot is not there. The inconsistency is distracting. I could go either way on this: 1. The red dot is always there whenever any review queue is greater than 200. 2. The red dot is only there whenever any review queue, that I have not maxed out my daily amount in, is over 200. Right now, the red dot is neither, so far as I can tell.

Can someone please confirm the exact conditions for when the red dot appears?

Comment: A post on Meta Stack Exchange related to the same problem: [Please remove the top bar indicator after completing review limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213249). It is marked as a duplicate of: [Don't display pending edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85366) (which is status-declined). However, this was marked (status-planned) in 2017: [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302093).

Comment: This older post on this meta is related to an extent - although it is about notification for users who cannot review close votes yet: [Should I be getting the “Red Dot” on the “Review Queues ” Icon?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27360)

Comment: This post might be useful: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226). It mentions that red dot appears 
1. if any review queue has a red dot (explained below) and; 2. if it’s been at least an hour since you clicked on the review icon. However, there are many details about how exactly this work. (But at least it's good to know that whether it is shown might depend on the last time you looked there.)

Comment: Currently I'm getting the red blob for the suggested edits queue—but when I visit the queue, I get a message that the queue has been cleared! So either the red blob is wrong or the message is.

Comment: I think the red dot for suggested edits shows up WAY earlier than for close votes: I could be wrong, but I think its threshold is only 10.