# Red dot on reopen queue but no items available to review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, notifications

I've been experiencing a red dot on the reopen queue intermittently over the past few weeks with no items available to review. Here's a screenshot of what the behavior looks like:

[image]

This screenshot was taken a couple days ago and replicated right before this posting - I clicked on the "Reopen votes" link (decorated with the red dot) from a normal page, got to the reopen votes page with the "this queue has been cleared" message, and then clicked on the dropdown menu to show that red dot still decorating the "Reopen votes" link. I suspect somehow the red dot for the close votes queue is "leaking over", but I can't be sure.

I've done some searching on meta about odd appearances of the red dot, but the chief complaint was about [review queues that people can't access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310798/please-dont-show-the-red-dot-indicator-for-review-items-i-cant-do) which is not this issue. Nor is this a duplicate of [this question about the red dot on the review icon](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29665/review-queues-bug), because my post deals with the red dot in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29665/review-queues-bug?

Comment: @MikeEarnest No, because this red dot is in the dropdown menu next to the reopen queue when the reopen queue is empty. That post is about the red dot on the menu bar.

Comment: I had this as well recently but I thought my connection was bad

Comment: Still have this. No one else? Should I blame caching?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I'm still getting it and I've seen a message or two complaining about it in the chatrooms by others who haven't said anything here. It might be time for me to repost this on global meta.

Comment: This is really getting annoying.... the red dot tricks me into clicking the reopen review queue, and the more I click, the more audits I trick myself into doing - 3 of my 10 recent reopen review are audits.

Comment: Now there is a red dot next to the Low quality posts review queue.... the virus is spreading.

Comment: @ArcticChar I can confirm this happens for me too: 0 items available to review in every queue except for close votes, yet red dots next to the close votes, reopen, and low quality queues.

Comment: Now the extra red dot on the low quality queue is gone, but the extra red dot on the reopen queue persists. Strange times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This is now fixed.

What happened:

- We show the red dot when the number of active items queue is over a specific number (can differ by queue and by site).
- The number of active items does not take into account specific tasks that the individual user cannot see. This number is calculated once every 10 minutes per queue per site.
- The issue: the query for calculating the number of active items was not filtering out audits. So for these queues (and others on many sites), there was a permanent red dot (or a red dot occurring much more often than needed) due to the active audit tasks being counted.

---

> Queue need attention?
> Check out red dot in top bar
> displayed correctly

Comment: Thank you for the fix and the explanation!